# screen brightness hotkeys worked live - not with installed

Tags: brightness

big thanks for the new Kubuntu 21, just installed this on my new Asus VivoBook-X513EA.

During the live session, when I tried Kubuntu the screen brightness hotkeys were working. But now in the installed version they don't ...

Thanks for help. The maximum brightness of this model is very harsh.

Comment: The problem is gone. Since I was online during installation I didn't expect updates coming right after the installation.  After second reboot it works now.

Comment: Kubuntu is a desktop release that is built on *deb* packages so uses the *yy.mm* format (year.month of release).  Ubuntu has used *yy* packages to mean *snap* only releases intended for headless appliances/devices/cloud since 2016, so there is no Kubuntu 21.